# How do I refresh a java applet?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, applet

I have a java applet that has a JButton in it. However, I'm displaying a chart in this applet and want to refresh the applet when that button is pushed. Is there something that does this?

I've already tried to add this:

```
setVisible(false);
//function that call a method
setVisible(true);
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Do you want to refresh applet (jar file) or just the chart?

Comment: We would need a lot more details of the code before making good recommendations.  What produces the chart?  Is it a custom `JPanel`, a 3rd party `Chart` etc.  Maybe a `CardLayout`, maybe changing parameters of the chart object, maybe.. ?  At the moment, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Make the necessary changes to the chart and call the component's repaint() method.

```
Chart c = new Chart(); // Chart extends Component (I assume)
// Call your update methods to make necessary changes
c.repaint(); // Forces the chart to be repainted
```

Edit: You may instead need to call the validate() method; I'm not completely sure and cannot test this right now.